# Xamarin custom renderer take photo

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, custom-renderer

I want to take photo using Xamarin form custom renderer.
I use **Custom Renderer Sample** and I add a Button named *'btnTakePicture'* in Xaml , but I don't have any idea how to take photo on Button click event.
I want to show camera in part of screen.
Also I checked **Xam.Media.Plugin** and I couldn't take photo.

**Xaml Code**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomRenderer;assembly=CustomRenderer"
             x:Class="CustomRenderer.frmCamera"
             Title="Main Page">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Label Text="Camera Preview"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <local:CameraPreview Camera="Rear" x:Name="cmrPreview"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Background="black"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button x:Name="btnChangeCamera" Text="Switch Camera" Clicked="btnChangeCamera_Clicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnTakePicture" Text="Take" Grid.Column="1" Clicked="btnTakePicture_Clicked"/>
        </Grid>
        <Frame></Frame>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**C# Code**

```
using System.IO;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CustomRenderer
{
    public partial class frmCamera : ContentPage
    {
        public frmCamera()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnChangeCamera_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmrPreview.Camera == CameraOptions.Rear)
                cmrPreview.Camera = CameraOptions.Front;
            else
                cmrPreview.Camera = CameraOptions.Rear;

        }

        bool blnIsFlashLight = false;
        private void btnFlashLight_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (blnIsFlashLight)
            {
                Flashlight.TurnOffAsync();
                blnIsFlashLight = false;
            }
            else
            {
                Flashlight.TurnOnAsync();
                blnIsFlashLight = true;
            }
        }

        private void btnTakePhoto_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[here is my project Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnZDe.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446520/how-to-take-a-picture-with-ios-camera-and-save-the-image-to-camera-roll-using-xa

Comment: its for ios,I wanna for android

Comment: that's the kind of information that might be useful to include in your post

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/monodroid-samples/android50-camera2basic/

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about or how that code is possibly relevant to the question you asked.

Comment: There is no way to take photo on my project?

Comment: I provided you with the link to samples of using the Camera with Xamarin Android.  If you are having problems making that work, you need to provide details about what you're doing and the **specific** problem that you're having.

Comment: I'm working on it. I am taking inspiration from Xamarin Community Toolkit code (https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit/Views/CameraView)